# Disjunctions in DataLog

Tags: datalog

So how are *OR* conditions emulated/invoked in *Datalog*-land ?

This is probably the most basic question ask-able about *DataLog* but well hello this is my first attempt at using it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it now: it's a strange syntax: disjunction is created by having multiple rules with the same name

```
myrecursive(X,Y) :- basecase1(Y,X). 
myrecursive(X,Y) :- myrecursive(X,Z),myrecursive(Z,Y).
```

This means that a `descendant` may satisfy either of those two rules.